# Haskell instance of typeclass definition with type constructor

Tags: haskell, constraints, typeclass

```
data CouldBe a = Is a | Lost deriving (Show, Ord)

instance Eq (CouldBe m) where
  Is x == Is y = x == y 
  Lost == Lost = True 
  _ == _ = False
```

Gives an error: `No instance for (Eq m) arising from a use of ‘==’`
So:

```
instance (Eq m) => Eq (CouldBe m) where
  Is x == Is y = x == y 
  Lost == Lost = True 
  _ == _ = False
```

Works fine (at least I start understanding the errors), but why do I need that constraint? 
I am trying to learn, so the 'why' is very important to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your original definition said that `CouldBe m` was an instance of `Eq` for *any* type `m`, even one that doesn't have an `Eq` instance. But if that's true, you have to find some way of defining `Is x == Is y` without using `x == y` (since you haven't required `m` to have an `Eq` instance, `x == y` isn't necessarily defined.)

As a specific example, it prevents you from writing something like

```
Is (+3) == Is (* 5)  -- (+3) == (*5) is undefined
```

Adding the constraint ensures you can compare two `CouldBe` values only if the wrapped type can also be compared.

---

A "valid", but trivial, instance without adding the constraint:

```
instance Eq (CouldBe m) where
  Is x == Is y = True
  Lost == Lost = True
  _ == _ = False
```

Two `CouldBe m` values are equal as long as they share the same data constructor, regardless of the wrapped value. No attempt is made to use `x` or `y` at all, so their types can be unconstrained.

"Valid" is in quotes because this definition could be in violation of the substitutivity law, defined at http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Eq.html. Suppose you had a function that could pull apart a `CouldBe` value:

```
couldbe :: b -> (a -> b) -> CouldBe a -> b
couldBe x _ Lost = x
couldBe _ f (Is x) = f x
```

The violation occurs because `Is 3 == Is 5` would be true, but let `f = couldbe 0 id`. Then `f (Is 3) == f (Is 5)` evaluates to `3 == 5` which is false.

Whether it's *actually* a violation or not depends on the existence of a function like `couldbe` that can see "inside" a `CouldBe` value.

Comment: Brilliant. Understandable and noted! Thx

Comment: I think if you're going to call the trivial instance "valid" you should point out that this only follows the Eq substitutivity law if you don't provide a way for clients to observe the value inside Is. More likely, those values are exposed, and so the trivial instance technically compiles but doesn't behave like an Eq instance should.

Comment: Thanks; I don't think I ever noticed the substitutivity law before.